# TypeError 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, typeerror

I'm trying to make a function the returns all possible permutations for a list of numbers for example:
List= [1,2,3]

[[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,1,2],[3,2,1]]

however I keep running into the same error
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
in this line

```
return permutations(result,variable,List,permutations)
```

the rest of the code is

```
def permutationsaux(List):
    if List==[]:
        return []
else:
    return permutations([List],0,List,countpermutations(List))

def permutations(result,variable,List,permutations):
    if len(result)==permutations:
        return result
    elif len(result[variable])==len(List):
        result.append([])
        variable=variable+1
        return permutations(result,variable,List,permutations)
    return permutations(result[variable]+reorderlist(List),variable+1,reorderlist(lista),permutations)

def countpermutations(List):
    if List==[]:
        return 1
    return len(List)*countpermutations(List[1:])

def reorderlist(List):
    temp=List[len(List)-2]
    List[len(List)-2]=LIst[len(List)-1]
    List[len(List)-1]=temp
    return List
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function "permutations" has an argument named "permutations". Guess which one is in scope within the function.